# in Vue: How do you implement the cell-class-name and row-class-name in the el-table of ElementUI?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using the ElementUI for vue. I'm trying to style the el-table rows and cells using CSS. There seems to be two functions that will do this, row-class-name and cell-class-name, but I do not know how to implement them.  The documentation is not clear: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table.

Does anybody have any examples/resources that I can look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
<template>
  <el-table
    :data="filteredBookings"
    :cell-class-name="cellClass"
    header-row-class-name="booking-table-header"
    row-class-name="booking-table-rows"
  >
    <el-table-column label="Status">
      <template slot-scope="tbl">
        {{ tbl.row.status }}
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column label="Course date" class="course-date">
      <template slot-scope="tbl">
        {{ tbl.row.date_from }}
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
</template>

<script>
export default
{ 
  methods:
  {
    cellClass(obj)
    {
      return obj.columnIndex === 0 ? 'booking-cell' : '';
    }, 
  }
}
</script>

<style>
    .el-table .cell
    {
      word-break: break-word;
    }

  tr.booking-table-header > th
  {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #EFF0F5;
  }

  .booking-table-rows
  {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .booking-cell
  {
    text-transform: none;
  }
 </style>
```

Comment: It would be great if the example would only contain the necessary elements and not a lot of additional information.

Comment: @Christian Do you like it now ?